# Angular: requisição Ajax

Tags: angularjs, ajax

O código abaixo não deveria estar funcionando?
Já testei no *console* e o texto que consta no arquivo 'teste' está vindo normalmente, só não aparece quando eu chamo com o `//demo.msg//`.

Onde estou errando?

SCRIPT

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.config(function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('//');
});

app.controller('DemoController', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get("/teste").then(function(response){
        $scope.msg = response.data;
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="DemoController as demo">
    //demo.msg//
</div>
```

Comment: Você está fazendo `{{ msg }}` apenas, né?

Comment: Era só tirar o demo mesmo. Não faltaram as chaves, é que como estou usando o blade do Laravel, precisei alterar o padrão do Angular de {{ para //. Valeu!

Comment: Blade se comenta assim: `{{-- msg --}}`.

Comment: Mas que bom que deu certo.